# Updating Formats

Tags: errors

I'm trying to update formats on MikTex 2.9 and receive the following error message:

```
miktex-makefmt.exe: Invalid control sequence.
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
initexmf.EXE: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-makefmt.exe
```

Originally my problem is that when I try to compile I receive the message:

```
pdflatex.exe: Invalid control sequence.
```

I figured updating formats would fix this?

Comment: Close all miktex related applications (YAP etc). Then open miktex-settings (admin or user) again, go to the format tab, select pdflatex and click on build. If you get an error try to capture as much informations as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to build pdflatex in the formats tab, but receive the following error message:

Comment: miktex-makefmt.exe: Invalid control sequence.
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
initexmf.EXE: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-makefmt.exe